# How can I pull in specific number of elements from a JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JS function that pulls in all the data based on search results. However, I want to now limit it to the top 6 listings. What is the quickest way to do that? I'm drawing complete blanks on it.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Your code here
    var $properties = $(".properties");
    myvr.properties().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        data.results.forEach(function (property) {
            console.log(property.name);
            $properties.append(
                '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">'+
                '<div class="min-height-smaller" style="background:url(' +
                property.photo.url +
                '); background-size:cover; background-position:center;"></div>' +
                '<p class="sub-heading">' +
                property.name +
                "</p>" +
                property.headline +
                "<br><br>" +
                ' <a class="primary-btn booking-link" data-property-id="' +
                property.key +
                '" href="/property/?p=' +
                property.slug+"&key="+property.key +
                '">Pricing and Details</a> <br><br></div>'
            );
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to limit. If you want to limit the results, only take the first 6 items from `data.results`; nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` to keep counter and add a condition `if(index < 6)` it will check if index value is less then **6** then only append values to div `properties` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//demo json datas
var data = {
  "results": [{
    "name": "something"
  }, {

    "name": "something1"
  }, {
    "name": "something3"
  }, {

    "name": "something4"
  }, {
    "name": "something5"
  }, {

    "name": "something6"
  }, {
    "name": "something7"
  }, {

    "name": "something8"
  }]
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $properties = $(".properties");
  //add index
  data.results.forEach(function(property, index) {
    //only append top 6 values
    if (index < 6) {
      $properties.append(
        "<p class='sub-heading'>" +
        property.name +
        "</p>"
      );
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="properties"></div>
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Just for an idea, if I were to down the line change it to display 6 random elements, is that a simple addition to what you did?

Comment: Hi you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/6nmehtLq/)

Comment: exactly that. Thank you again!

Comment: Your welcome .Happy coding :) .Modify that code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JQuery.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```js
var $properties = $(".properties").slice(0,6);

$properties.addClass("red");
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="properties">1</div>
<div class="properties">2</div>
<div class="properties">3</div>
<div class="properties">4</div>
<div class="properties">5</div>
<div class="properties">6</div>
<div class="properties">7</div>
<div class="properties">8</div>
<div class="properties">9</div>
<div class="properties">10</div>
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it still displays all of the results that get pulled in by the array

Comment: it seems like it may have something to do with doing the append to the HTML element: <div class="properties"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const teams = document.querySelectorAll('.standings ol li');

teams.forEach((team, idx) => {
  if(idx < 4) {
    team.classList.add('champions-league');
  }
  
  if(idx == 4) {
    team.classList.add('europa-league');
  }
  
  const relegationIdxs = Array.from({length: 3}, (_, i) => (teams.length - 1) - i);
  
  if(relegationIdxs.includes(idx)) {
    team.classList.add('relegation');
  }
});
```

```css
.standings {
  --champions-league: #4285F4;
  --europa-league: #FA7B17;
  --relegation: #EA4335;
  
  background: #F8F9FA;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #EBEBEB;
}

.champions-league {
  color: var(--champions-league);
}

.europa-league {
  color: var(--europa-league);
}

.relegation {
  color: var(--relegation);
}

.legend span {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px 3px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span:before {
  content: "■";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

span[status="champions-league"]:before {
  color: var(--champions-league)
}

span[status="europa-league"]:before {
  color: var(--europa-league)
}

span[status="relegation"]:before {
  color: var(--relegation)
}
```

```html
<div class="standings">
  <div class="legend">
    <span status="champions-league">UEFA Champions League</span>
    <span status="europa-league">Europa League</span>
    <span status="relegation">Relegation</span>
  </div>
  
  <ol>
    <li>Real Madrid</li>
    <li>Barcelona</li>
    <li>Atletico Madrid</li>
    <li>Valencia</li>
    <li>Real Sociedad</li>
    <li>Getafe</li>
    <li>Sevilla</li>
    <li>Levante</li>
    <li>Eibar</li>
    <li>Elche</li>
    <li>Osasuna</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```